# How can I calculate neighborhood overlap in weighted network?

Tags: graph, networkx

How can I calculate neighborhood overlap between two nodes (i,j) in a weighted graph?

"...we define the neighborhood overlap of an edge connecting A and B to be the ratio: (number of nodes who are neighbors of both A and B)/ (number of nodes who are neighbors of at least one of A or B) where in the denominator we don’t count A or B themselves (even though A is a neighbor of B and B is a neighbor of A)."

https://www.cs.cornell.edu/home/kleinber/networks-book/networks-book-ch03.pdf

Comment: What is the neighborhood overlap? What have you tried so far?

Comment: "...we define the neighborhood overlap of an edge connecting A and
B to be the ratio:

(number of nodes who are neighbors of both A and B)/
(number of nodes who are neighbors of at least one of A or B) 

where in the denominator we don’t count A or B themselves (even though A is a neighbor of
B and B is a neighbor of A)."
https://www.cs.cornell.edu/home/kleinber/networks-book/networks-book-ch03.pdf

Answer (score 2):

`networkx` has a built-in function to find the common neighbors of two nodes in a graph: [`common_neighbors`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.classes.function.common_neighbors.html). Now we only need to find the number of nodes that are neighbors to either A or B. Note that

```
| N(u) ⋃ N(v) | = |N(u)| + |N(v)| - | N(u) ⋂ N(v)|
```

where `N(u)` is the set of neighbors of `u`. Since we don't count A or B in the denominator, we need to subtract 2 from `| N(u) ⋃ N(v) |`.

```python
def neighborhood_overlap(g, u, v):
    n_common_nbrs = len(set(nx.common_neighbors(g, u, v)))
    n_join_nbrs = g.degree(u) + g.degree(v) - n_common_nbrs - 2
    return n_common_nbrs / n_join_nbrs
```

However, you still need to decide what happens if the denominator is 0, i.e., when the nodes A and B form a connected component of the graph.

Answer (score 1):

I know the tag of the question is `networkx`, but since this is the first thing that pop ups on Google, on `igraph` the function would be

```
neighborhood_overlap <- function(g, node1, node2)
{
  nh1 = neighborhood(graph=g, order=1, nodes=node1)[[1]]
  nh2 = neighborhood(graph=g, order=1, nodes=node2)[[1]]
  common = intersect(nh1, nh2)
  commonl = length(common)
  # | N(u) ⋃ N(v) | = |N(u)| + |N(v)| - | N(u) ⋂ N(v)|
  union = degree(net_vc, v=node1) + degree(net_vc, v=node2) - commonl - 2
  return(commonl/union)
}
```